# How to get single occurrences of only certain characters?

Tags: android, string, char, character, stringbuilder

I have the following code to pick find any two of the same letters next to each other and remove one.

For example: `singleOccurrence("1//2/2018")`

My code:

```
public static StringBuilder singleOccurrence(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (s.length() > 0) {
        char prev = s.charAt(0);
        sb.append(prev);
        for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); ++i) {
            char cur = s.charAt(i);
            if (cur != prev) {
                sb.append(cur);
                prev = cur;
            }
        }
    }
    return sb;
}
```

This will return: "1/2/2018"

However, if I inputted: `singleOccurrence("11//2/2018")`
It would return: "1/2/2018"

Notice that my method removes double occurrences of all characters.

My question is how do I make my method only do what it's supposed to do with the characters `"/", "-", ":"`

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into your if statement. That checks if prev & cur characters are not '-' '/' or ':' append to result.

```
if (cur != prev || (cur != '-' || cur != '/' || cur != ':')) 
{
   sb.append(cur);
   prev = cur;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, but unfortunately that did what I needed, however it still allowed double occurrences of "/", "-", ":" to appear.

Comment: Sorry, it should be if (cur != prev || (cur != '-' && cur != '/' && cur != ':'))

Answer (score 1):

```
public void singleOccurrence(String string) 
{
    char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
    List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();
    char temp = 0;
    for (char c : chars) {
        if (temp != c || (c != '/' && c != '_' && c != ':')) {
            characters.add(c);
        }
        temp = c;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Character character : characters) {
        sb.append(character);
    }

    Log.e(TAG, sb.toString());
}
```

Hope it can help you!